# Meaning of fiddler pencil icon

Tags: fiddler

What is the meaning of the following icon next to a request in Fiddler's web sessions (looks like a pencil writing on a sheet of paper)?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/51uc8.jpg]

It isn't listed in the [quick reference](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/ui.asp).

Comment: Is there anything about the request that differentiates it from requests that get an expected icon?

Comment: No. I'm issuing regular GETs and POSTs. The exact same requests usually get the standard icon.

Comment: Answer found:
When pressing F2, the currently highlighted session becomes editable, and the icon changes to the above. Pressing F2 again reverts to the former state.
(same effect achieved by right-click -> Unlock For Editing)

Comment: Cool. You can (and should) post that as an answer and accept it, although I suspect that as a new user the system doesn't let you do this immediately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer found:

When pressing <kbd>F2</kbd>, the currently highlighted session becomes editable, and the icon changes to the above. Pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> again reverts to the former state.
(same effect achieved by right-click -> Unlock For Editing)